# Перевод Case в функцию

Tags: c++

Здраствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста. Есть программа на с++, нужно в ней изменить выборку `Case`, переделать её в функцию. Можно это как-то осуществить? Код ниже. Заранее спасибо за ответы!

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()
{
int i, dlina, j, q;
char  s[100], d[100], r[50];
clrscr();
printf("Vvedite pravila:\n");
gets(r);

s[0]='S';
s[1]='\0';
for (q=0;q<16;q++)
{
 switch (r[q])
  {
   case '1':
   {for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {if (s[i]=='S')
     {for (j=0;j<i;j++) d[j]=s[j];
      for (j=i;j<strlen(s)+2;j++) d[j+2]=s[j+1];
      d[i]='b';
      d[i+1]='S';
     }
    }
    for (j=0;j<=strlen(d);j++) s[j]=d[j];
   }; break;

     case '2':
   {for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {if (s[i]=='S')
     {for (j=0;j<i;j++) d[j]=s[j];
      for (j=i;j<strlen(s)+2;j++) d[j+2]=s[j+1];
      d[i]='B';
      d[i+1]='S';
     }
    }
    for (j=0;j<=strlen(d);j++) s[j]=d[j];
   }; break;

      case '3':
   {for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {if (s[i]=='B')
     {for (j=0;j<i;j++) d[j]=s[j];
      for (j=i;j<strlen(s)+2;j++) d[j+2]=s[j+1];
      d[i]='a';
      d[i+1]='B';
     }
    }
    for (j=0;j<=strlen(d);j++) s[j]=d[j];
   }; break;

      case '4':
   {for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {if (s[i]=='B')
     {for (j=0;j<i;j++) d[j]=s[j];
      for (j=i;j<strlen(s)+2;j++) d[j+2]=s[j+1];
      d[i]='a';
      d[i+1]='S';
     }
    }
    for (j=0;j<=strlen(d);j++) s[j]=d[j];
   }; break;

      case '5':
   {for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {if (s[i]=='S')
     {for (j=0;j<i;j++) d[j]=s[j];
      for (j=i;j<strlen(s);j++) d[j]=s[j+1];
     }
    }
    for (j=0;j<=strlen(d);j++) s[j]=d[j];
   }; break;
  }
}
printf("%s\n",&s);
getch();
}
```

Спасибо за ответы. Вот задание:

[image]

Comment: Всё-таки, что за цель у этого кода? Что он должен делать?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Вот задание: http://i30.fastpic.ru/big/2011/1108/6e/690984af4dae4c90c657b92b1b170f6e.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*В вашей программе есть несколько повторяющихся блоков вида (**[да-да](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)**):*

```
   {for (i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
    {if (s[i]=='S')
     {for (j=0;j<i;j++) d[j]=s[j];
      for (j=i;j<strlen(s);j++) d[j]=s[j+1];
     }
    }
    for (j=0;j<=strlen(d);j++) s[j]=d[j];
   }; break;
  }
```

Честно сказать, я не стал разбираться, что эти участки кода делают, однако на один такой участок приходится по 3-4 переменных параметра, а все остальные операции полностью идентичны.

**Таким образом, вам необходимо:**

1. Выделить для всех этих блоков переменные, которые могут меняться. Это сами строчки, `char'ы` типа `B` и длины строк типа `+2`.
2. Написать общий вид функции, заменив эти самые изменяемые переменные на некоторые общие имена, например, `usedChar` и `addedLength`.
3. Выделить общий вид функции в отдельный прототип и передать ему изменяемые выражения через параметры.
4. Заменить ваш код на вызовы соответствующей функции в `case'ах`.

*В итоге вы получите код по типу:*

```
case 5:
    RunMyActions(s, d, 'B', 2);
    break;
case 7:
    RunMyActions(s, d, 'S', 4);
    break;
// И так далее.
```

---

*Тоже, конечно, не фонтан, но явно лучше, нежели первоначальный вариант. Если интересно, могу рассказать, как такой код рефакторится дальше.*

#### Update

---

Отлично, едем дальше. *Приведу небольшой прототип кода на `C++`, который может являться результатом рефакторинга вашего кода.*

```
#include <string>

enum Rule { RULE_1, RULE_2, ... };

// См. 'ApplyRuleToString'.
std::string ApplyRuleToStringHelper(const std::string& s, int ruleParameter1, int ruleParameter2, ...) {
   // Скопируем строчку и проведем какие-то действия с ней, механика
   // которых обусловлена переданными параметрами.
   std::string result = s;
   if (ruleParameter1 == 1) {
       result = "Йа кросафчег!";
   }

   return result;
}

// Метод для применения некоторого правила к строке.
std::string ApplyRuleToString(const std::string& s, Rule rule) {
    // Применить правило 'rule' к строчке.
    // Можно решить с помощью применения 'switch' и вспомогательного
    // метода, который аналогичен 'RunMyActions' в примере выше.
    switch (rule) {
    case RULE_1:
        return ApplyRuleToStringHelper(s, 100500, 42, ...);
    case RULE_2:
        // Аналогично.

    // Для каких-то специфических правил возможно использование любого другого
    // метода-helper'a.
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Можно получить из консоли очевидным способом.
    const std::string s = "Йа кросафчег?";
    const Rule rule = RULE_1;
    const std::string result = ApplyRuleToString(s, RULE_1);
    // В 'result' хранится итоговый результат всей операции.
}
```

**Понятно, что такой подход легко обобщается на произвольные правила трансформации строки, в том числе и на правила, заданные в вашей исходной программе.**

Comment: Спасибо, было бы интересно почитать как код рефакторится дальше.

Answer (score 1):

Ужасный код. Зачем в цикле делать проверку strlen? Она будет вызываться каждую итерацию, лучше вынести это за цикл. Весь цикл можно заменить на:

```
//... то что было перед циклом
const char arr1[]={'S', 'S', 'B', 'B', 'S'};
const char arr2[]={'b', 'B', 'a', 'a'};
const char arr3[]={'S', 'S', 'B', 'S'};
for(q=0; q<16; q++)
{
    int index=r[q]-1;
    if(index<0 || index>4) continue;
    int slen=strlen(s);
    for(i=0; i<slen; i++)
    {
        if(s[i]!=arr1[index]) continue;
        memcpy(d, s, i);
        memcpy(d+i+2, s+i+1, slen+2-i);
        if(index!=4)
        {
            d[i]=arr2[index];
            d[i+1]=arr3[index];
        }
    }
    strcpy(s, d);
}
//... то что идёт после цикла
```

Не правда ли стало короче? И это я ещё не использовал функции. Если я нигде не ошибся, этот код должен быть полностью эквивалентным исходному циклу. Я убрал switch с повторяющимся кодом при помощи табличного поиска. Код конечно ещё можно улучшить, но я не знаю, что он делает, поэтому не могу назвать переменные понятнее.

Comment: `strlen` в цикле не будет вызываться каждый раз, а вот `int slen = strlen(...)` как раз загромождает код.

Comment: Почему? Оптимизация компилятора?

Comment: Уважаемый @Котик_хочет_кушать, почему Вы считаете, что не будет вызываться каждый раз? И очень даже будет. В конце каждой итерации должно проверяться условие. Как оно будет проверяться, если не будет вызвана функция и получено возвращаемое ею значение? Кроме того, можете проверить опытным путем.

Comment: [**Смотрите сами.**][1] Вообще говоря, `strlen`-подобные функции помечены как `не изменяющие state`, поэтому такие вызовы легко оптимизируются. *Есть, конечно, некоторые особенные случаи с использованием `volatile`, но их уже нужно разбирать отдельно.*

-------

Говоря короче, вещи типа `int slen = ::strlen(...)` - это еще одно проявление синдрома преждевременной оптимизации.

[1]: http://pastie.org/2830840

Comment: >Говоря короче, вещи типа int slen = ::strlen(...) - это еще одно проявление синдрома преждевременной оптимизации

 А я думал наоборот, что применение strlen в цикле - это пессимизация. Как их отличать тогда?

Comment: В этом случае вынос strlen() я бы назвал аккуратностью программирования, а не преждевременной оптимизацией. 

Но данная задача улучшается не "рефакторингом" кода, а разбиением алгоритма на независимые части или его обобщением.

Comment: Хм, я же вроде продемонстрировал ассемблерный листинг, где `strlen` заоптимизился. Ладно, это, видимо, дело привычки, но лично я считаю запись `i < ::strlen(s)` наиболее компактной и понятной *(разве что она уступает `foreach(char c, s)` в плане понятности).*

Comment: Хорошо, если соптимизируется. Правда, я не понимаю тогда авторов библиотеки. А вдруг во время итерации будет изменена строка? Что тогда?

Comment: @mikillskegg Да авторы библиотеки здесь совершенно ни при чем. В случае, если внутри цикла доступа к строке нет **(как и в вопросе автора)**, то оптимизация будет проведена. В случае, если строка внутри меняется каким-либо образом, оптимизация может быть проведена, а может и не быть, если компилятор посчитает, что размер строки может измениться.

-----

Я вообще это все говорю к тому, что в таких местах стоит сначала написать хороший и читаемый код, а только потом выдирать из цикла переменные, т.к `int slen = ...` явно не способствует читаемости.

Comment: Понятие "читаемости" очень относительное. Если, конечно, переменную объявить в начале текста, а использовать в конце, это плохо. Ну а если сразу после объявления использовать, это (на мой дилетантский взгляд) вполне нормально.

Comment: Ладно, про strlen закончили. Что скажете об остальном? Замена вложенных циклов на memcpy (который вдобавок работает быстрее, потому что копирует порциями по 4 байта). Избавился от повторяющегося кода при помощи массива.

Comment: Можно вообще без стрлен for(j=0; d[j]; j++) s[j]=d[j];
а еще помнится есть такая функция strcpy(d,s);

Comment: Отредактировал код. Теперь dlen вообще не нужен. Заменил циклы на memcpy и strcpy.

Comment: int slen=strlen(s);
    for(i=0; i<slen; i++)
здесь тоже можно без стрлен. Возможно я скажу очевидную вещь, но конец строки символов в си/си++ обозначается символом с кодом 0, поэтому здесь можно обойтись for(i=0; s[i]; i++)

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял исходник, то требуется менять в строке (сдвигая "хвост" вправо) 'S' на "bS",'S' на "BS",'B' на "aB" и 'S' на "" в соответствии с введенным номером правила.

Все становится очень просто и понятно

```
gets(r);

while (*r) {
    switch (*r++) {
    case '1':
       replace(s,'S',"bS");
       break;
    case '2':
       replace(s,'S',"BS");
       break;
    case '3':
       replace(s,'B',"aB");
       break;
    case '4':
       replace(s,'B',"aS");
       break;
    case '5':
       replace(s,'S',"");
    }
}
```

Осталось написать replace(), думаю автор справится.

Несколько ухудшая понятность, но увеличивая общность можно задать массив структур (5 шт)

```
   struct rule {
      char letter;
      char *repstr;
   };
   struct rule rules[5] = { {'S',"bS"}, ....};
```

и выбирать из него по номеру правила (соответственно обработав этот номер). Думаю тоже все очевидно.

KISS - принцип.

Comment: struct rule {
      char letter;
      char repstr[3];
   };

Comment: @insolor, а почему char repstr[3] ?  Чем менее ограниченная char \* не нравится ?

Comment: Хм, теперь уже ничем. Не думал что такая инициализация сработает, но факт на лицо.